# Populate the RecyclerView List

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I can't seem to get my `RecyclerView` to populate all the way. It only makes the first cell, and the others are blank. Even though the for loop seems to run multiple times.

```
    JsonObjectRequest root = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject feed = response.getJSONObject("feed");
                JSONArray results = feed.getJSONArray("results");
                //Log.d("FEED", String.valueOf(feed));w
                for(int i = 0; i<results.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject resultsObj = results.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.d(TAG, "inside" + String.valueOf(i));
                    mImageUrls.add(resultsObj.getString("artworkUrl100"));
                    mTitle.add(resultsObj.getString("name"));
                    getRecyclerView();
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(root);

}

private void getRecyclerView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getRecyclerView");
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImageUrls, mTitle, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}
```

Comment: put `getRecyclerView();` outside the loop, i.e, just before `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is not needed. Just put getRecyclerView(); outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you initialize the adapter with one value. That's why the list contains one value and others were blank. You need to move `getRecyclerView();` to outside the loop.

Look like this:

```
try {
            JSONObject feed = response.getJSONObject("feed");
            JSONArray results = feed.getJSONArray("results");
            //Log.d("FEED", String.valueOf(feed));w
            for(int i = 0; i<results.length(); i++){
                JSONObject resultsObj = results.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d(TAG, "inside" + String.valueOf(i));
                mImageUrls.add(resultsObj.getString("artworkUrl100"));
                mTitle.add(resultsObj.getString("name"));

            }
             getRecyclerView();
           // No need to notify the data set changed 
           // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this works:

```
JsonObjectRequest root = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject feed = response.getJSONObject("feed");
                JSONArray results = feed.getJSONArray("results");
                //Log.d("FEED", String.valueOf(feed));w
                for(int i = 0; i<results.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject resultsObj = results.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.d(TAG, "inside" + String.valueOf(i));
                    mImageUrls.add(resultsObj.getString("artworkUrl100"));
                    mTitle.add(resultsObj.getString("name"));
                }

                getRecyclerView();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(root);

}

private void getRecyclerView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getRecyclerView");
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImageUrls, mTitle, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); }
```

What I did was move `getRecyclerView();` outside the loop, because you only need to call it once, not each time you want to set the recyclerview.

Comment: but that's the answer :)

Comment: @jason18401 please close this question by accepting my answer by clicking on the green tick icon beside my answer. Would be great if you could give me an upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be it help you.

```
private void getRecyclerView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getRecyclerView");
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImageUrls, mTitle, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}
```